# SAPUI5 binding issue: list item links maintained in json file do not work

Tags: javascript, json, binding, sapui5

following situation. I have a table defined in an xml view (text content is located in a json file). For every list item, there's a press event defined so that a click on the item takes me to another page or opens a file. Everything is properly displayed but the click event does not work. Please provide feedback. Thanks.

```
  <VBox
id="idVBox">
<items>

  <Table id="idProductsTable"   inset="false"
items="{
  path: '/ProductCollection',
  sorter: {
    path: 'Name'
  }
}">

<columns>
  <Column>
  </Column>

</columns>

<items>

  <ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press="{target}" >
    <cells >
      <ObjectIdentifier 
        title="{Name}"
        class="sapMTableContentMargin" />


    </cells>
  </ColumnListItem>
</items>
    </Table>

</items>
```

The json looks like this:

```
{"ProductCollection": [
    { 
     "Name" : "blabla1",
    "target" : "ee1" },
 { 
    "Name" : "blabla2",
  "target" : "ee2"
  }, ....
```

In a js controller, I defined the targets like:

```
        onInit: function() {
    this.bus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();

    // set explored app's demo model on this sample
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/scopelist.json");
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);

    // Append demo table into VBox, making a minor modification
    // to the first column so that the Category information is shown
    var oTable = this.getView().byId("idProductsTable");

    var oBindingInfo = oTable.getBindingInfo("items");
    oBindingInfo.template.removeCell(0);
    oBindingInfo.template.insertCell(new sap.m.ObjectIdentifier({
        title: "{Name}",
        text: "{Category}"
    }));
    oTable.bindItems(oBindingInfo);
    this.getView().byId("idVBox").addItem(oTable);
}, ....

 ee1: function() {
    window.open("something1.pdf", "_blank");
},
ee2: function() {
    window.open("./docu/something2.pdf", "_blank");
}, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `press` event supports data binding, i.e. allows for dynamic function naming.

The recommended approach is to just reference a named event handler:

```
press="handlePress"
```

and in your controller create the event handler:

```
handlePress: function(oEvent) {
    // get the current object from your table array
    var obj = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getObject();

    if (obj.target === "ee1") {
        //do something
    }
    else if (obj.target === "ee2") {
        //do something else
    }
}
```